# How to solve this problem using recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

My function has to be able to print the sum of the numbers 1+1+1.... to get to N. I can only enter N. For example: `sumaRecursiva(6): 1+1+1+1+1+1=6`.
This is what I have:

```
int sumaRecursiva(int y) {
    
    int x=0;
    if (x == y){
        return y;
    }
    else {
        
        x += 1;
        cout << x << "+" <<endl;
        sumaRecursiva(y-1);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print the sequence, or just return the sum? You don't need recursion if you just want the sum.

Comment: Your function is malformed in that you only return a value when y is 0. You probably need to change the recursion call to say `return sumaRecursiva(y-1);`

Answer (score 1):

You may want another function to handle the fact that you need fewer `+` characters in your print than you need `1`s

```
void printSum(int y) {
  if (y == 0) return;
  cout << 1;
  printPlusRecursive(y - 1);   
}

void printPlusRecursive(int y) {
  if (y == 0) return;
  cout << '+' << 1;
  printPlusRecursive(y - 1);
}
```

or shorter, but more complex version:

```
void printSum(int y, bool firstCall = true) {
  if (y == 0) return;
  if (firstCall) cout << 1;
  else cout << '+' << 1;
  printSum(y - 1, false);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output to be exactly `1+1+1+1+1+1=6` then you will need a helper function sumaRecursivaHelper to print the `1+`'s and the outer function to print the `=n` which I believe none of the other answers include.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void sumaRecursivaHelper(int x) {
  if (x == 0) {
      cout << 1;
  }
  else {
      cout << "1+";
      sumaRecursivaHelper(x - 1);
  }
}

void sumaRecursiva(int x) {
  if (x == 0) {
      cout << 0;
  }
  else {
      sumaRecursivaHelper(x); 
  }
  cout << "=" << x;
}

int main()
{
    sumaRecursiva(6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: End what about "endl" !?

Answer (score -1):

Your recursive function should return a value.
The value passed to a recursive is usually used to test for the escape condition (not usually used as part of the result).

```
int sum(int N)
{
    if (N == 0) {
        return 0; // I like zero as the escape value.
                  // Though this will give you
                  // sum(6) = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 6
                  // If you only want to add ones change
                  // the escape condition to 1 and return 1
                  // Though this will prevent you doing sum(0)
    }
    return 1 + sum(N-1);
}
```